# Integrate command to calculate definite integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'm trying to evaluate the following expression:

[image]

where 0 < x 0 y.

I'm using the following command, but can't get it to return a result.

```
Integrate[
  t^{z}*Log[t], {t, x, y},
  Assumptions -> z ∈ Integers, 
  Assumptions -> y > x > 0
]
```

Where am going wrong?

Comment: 1) Use only one `Assumptions` and combine your assumptions in a list `{...}` 2) do NOT use curly braces around your $z$. In short `Integrate[t^z*Log[t], {t, x, y}, 
 Assumptions -> {z \[Element] Integers, y > x > 0}]`

Answer (score 2):

Try (only one `Assumption->...`, no curly brackets `{z}` )

```
Integrate[t^z *Log[t], {t, x, y},Assumptions -> {z\[Element] PositiveIntegers, y > x > 0}]
(*(x^(1 + z) (1 - (1 + z) Log[x]) + y^(1 + z) (-1 + (1 + z) Log[y]))/(1 + z)^2*)
```

Comment: Thank you, still yields no result though.

Comment: @Orm Yields a result for me in *Mathematica* 13.0.

Comment: After reboot it works. Thanks all!!

Comment: The assumptions can be relaxed `Assuming[y > x >= 0, Integrate[t^z*Log[t], {t, x, y}]]`

Answer (score 1):

First calculate the antiderivative:

```
ad[t_] = Integrate[t^z*Log[t], t, Assumptions -> z \[Element] Integers]
```

Then you can calculate the definite integral by:

```
ad[y]-ad[x] // Simplify
```

[image]